# normalize a column to represent it as a size in a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a column with small to fairly large values in a dataframe column: sizes. I would like to use this column as a size in a scatter as shown [here](http://matthiaseisen.com/pp/patterns/p0171/):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n = 50
x = np.random.randn(n)
y = x * np.random.randn(n)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(6, 6))

ax[0].scatter(x, y, s=50)

sizes = (np.random.randn(n) * 8) ** 2
ax[1].scatter(x, y, s=sizes)

fig.show()
```

What is the best way to normalise the column: sizes. I tried to log it but the sizes turn out to look too similar. The proportions should still represent the proportions in the original column.

Comment: Can you share some representative data?

Comment: That would be hard - sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends what message you want to convey with your plot.

If the proportions of the scaled sizes should be the same as the original data, then you can only linearly scale the sizes. If you allow non-linear scaling, then you have to decide where you want to squeeze/expand the input data so that in these regions the size of a circle for input value `x` is not twice the size for input `x/2`.

I will assume that the largest size you want to plot is 500, i.e. `max(sizes)=500` and the maximum of your input data is 2000, but the actual values do not really matter.

I created a plot with some options.

[image]

For linear scaling (green curve) you just have to find the maximum of your input data and then scale with `sizes=input_data*500/max_val`.

You could also use different variations of the `tanh` function for scaling. For example, if you want to plot data below some threshold with rather small circles and above that threshold with larger circles, you could choose something like the blue curve. You can make the curve much steeper by changing `tanh(x/500-2)*250+250` to `tanh(x/50-20)*250+250`.

The tanh solutions have the nice feature that very large input values are still mapped to the maximum size 500. This does not work, if you use for example a parabolic scaling where the size of the circle would grow unbounded. So for example, if your input data ranges from 0 to 10^6 but you only want to visualize changes up to 2000 and all values larger than 2000 should get the same size, than the tanh scaling can help you achieve that.

Without some actual data it is hard to predict which scaling works best for you.

Comment: This is a nice explanation and the graphic really helps. I'll add that tanh is a numpy function and, assuming numpy imported as np, called as np.tanh()